# Makefile that runs different processes in different prompts

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile, prompt

I'm creating a Makefile that runs a `process manager.c` and another process `supermarket.c` after the first one. I was wondering if it was possible to do it in a way that it opens one shell window for each file, since, at the moment, I get the output of both processes in the same prompt and It's pretty confusing to me.

Here is my Makefile:

```
all: manager supermarket

manager: manager.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(THREADS) -o manager manager.c

    
supermarket: supermarket.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(THREADS) -o supermarket supermarket.c


test2:  
    @echo [+] Starting Manager process...
    @./manager & echo $$! > m.PID
    @echo [+] Manager is running...
    @echo [+] Starting Supermarket process...
    @./supermarket 6 50 3 200 100 20 & echo $$! > sm.PID
    @echo [+] Supermarket is running...
    @sleep 25
    
    if [ -e m.PID ]; then \
        echo [+] Sending SIGHUP to Manager process...; \
        kill -1 $$(cat m.PID) || true; \
        echo [+] Manager waiting Supermarket to close...; \
        while sleep 1; do ps -p $$(cat sm.PID) 1>/dev/null || break; done; \
    fi;
    
    @rm m.PID
    @rm sm.PID
    @echo
    @echo
    @./analisi.sh $(LOG_FN)
    @echo
    @echo
```

Comment: You can run `xterm -e <command>` to start an xterm window running `<command>`.

Comment: Putting [backslashed] shell commands in a Makefile tortures `make` and provides less control. Put the shell commands into a separate shell script just invoke that. If you must, you can do: `test2: ./myscript`. As to separate windows, you can do (e.g.) `xterm -e ./supermarket 6 50 3 200 100 20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running separate terminals out of a `Makefile` is rather problematic, as it doesn't interface well with the general flow of `make`.  A better solution is probably to have each process output its results to a log file, and then separately launch an `xterm` or what have you to run `tail -f` on each file for your interactive needs.

```
all: manager supermarket

manager: manager.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(THREADS) -o manager manager.c

supermarket: supermarket.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(THREADS) -o supermarket supermarket.c


test2:  
    ./manager >manager.log 2>&1 & \
    echo $$! > m.PID
    ./supermarket 6 50 3 200 100 20  >supermarket.log 2>&1 & \
    echo $$! > sm.PID

    sleep 25

    cat m.PID sm.PID | xargs kill -1 
    wait $$(cat m.PID sm.PID)
    rm -f m.PID sm.PID

    ./analisi.sh $(LOG_FN)
```

Really, don't litter your `Makefile` with `@` (you can run it with `make -s` if you don't want to see what's going on) and probably reduce the amount of human-readable status updates.

Comment: What command exactly will launch a terminal depends on your OS. Traditionally, X11 provided `xterm` or some other command with the same name, but this still doesn't translate well to MacOS or, well, the less fortunate platform for the unwashed masses. Increasingly, different Linux desktop environments provide their own `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` or what have you,

Comment: Thank you very much. But after adjusting the makefile like you suggested I have two problems. The supermarket.log file has all the information correctly, meanwhile the manager.log file has some strange characters like "䥓䡇偕挠瑡档摥" and I don't know why. Also I get "Error 127" after the "wait" and both the PIDs aren't removed.

Comment: We can't know what `manager` is supposed to print; probably post a separate question about that with more details.

Comment: The `kill` probably kills the processes right off so that you might not be able to successfully `wait` on them. Your earlier code looked like you expected them to linger after the kill. But this is easy to fix; just add a minus before the `wait` to ignore any failure from this command.